# Mobile app emulation able to connect to online application service but not working on actual device

Tags: java, android, ios, ssl, tcp

I'm currently trying to solve an issue with a mobile application that is throwing a "Error communicating with application service' alert upon being launched.

- The error occurs on both ios and android versions of the app across
  multiple device's, wifi, 4G etc.
- An emulation of the application using Android Studios DOES work. The 
  app successfully communicates with the sites API. I can see all of
  this information on the logcat within Android Studio.
- The mobile application has not been updated recently, the local version i'm
  running the emulation with is identical to the live version. The app
  hasn't been updated prior to the error occurring.
- The domain/URL that the application is connecting to has recently had
  a Certificate Signup Request generated for the SSL certificate that expires
  in a few months. I'm not sure if this is relevant however I have read
  that a emulated device handles https differently to an actual device.

To further diagnose the issue on an actual device I'm looking into "tcpdump" as it can potentially show everything that is happening on the device. I've tried using LogcatExtreme but it doesn't show a more verbose detailing of the error that is occurring.

Here is a link to the application that you can download right now. If anyone believes this is a security risk, please let me know and I will take it down. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.silkhospitality.Silk

Even though I haven't exhausted all avenues of diagnosis I wanted to ask the community before I potentially end up in a culdesac.

Comment: You mean `cul-de-sac` ?  Anyway, what Exception are you getting, please add the stacktrace to this question

Answer (score 0):

Both the Android and iOS version of the application in question were redeployed to their respective app stores in order to solve this. The real reason for them failing to connect to the application was never discovered. These applications were both 5+ years old and needed some minor environmental changes to be made but none of the core programming was changed/altered in order to successfully redeploy.